# PowerBI Conditional Column with multiple different conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to created a new column in my dataset based on some other fields. I want to use this then as a filter for my visuals.

I have created a switch formula for 95% of my customers fall into. I have a few exceptions and I am wondering how I could cater for them.

Eg:

```
VAR _1 = IF ('Table'[Customer ID] = "Customer 1011" && 'Table'[ITEM Cat] <> "House", "USA" , "EUROPE')
VAR _2 = IF('Table'[Customer ID] = "Customer 1013" && 'Table'[OrderDate] < "2021/07/01", "Europe", "USA")
```

This is the switch code so far I have:

```
PostalCode = SWITCH([Customer ID] , 
        "Customer 1001" ,  "USA",
        "Customer 1002" ,"EU",
        "Customer 1003" , "ASIA",
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to combine VAR_1, VAR_2 and Postalcode to one formula?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get all the "normal conditions" with the abnormal ones all together in one column and then use it as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use switch this way:

```
YourColumn = SWITCH( 
TRUE(),
'Table'[Customer ID] = "Customer 1011" && 'Table'[ITEM Cat] <> "House", "USA",
'Table'[Customer ID] = "Customer 1013" && 'Table'[OrderDate] < "2021/07/01", "Europe",
"ELSEHERE"
)
```

https://dax.guide/switch/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: Error came back

Function 'SWITCH' does not support comparing values of type True/False with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.